# Canvas.FillText not working in TGrid.OnDrawColumnCell event handler

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I am having difficulty understanding what is going on in a FireMonkey owner-drawn grid I am trying to develop in Delphi 10.3.

I have set the `Grid1.DefaultDrawing` property to False and assigned the following event handler to `Grid1.OnColumnCellDraw`:

```pascal
procedure TFormFolderCptPairArray.Grid1DrawColumnCell1(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  Grid: TGrid;
  ColIndex, RowIndex: integer;
  CellStr: string;
  CellStringSize: TSizeF;
  CellStrPosn: TPointF;
  CellStrRect: TRectF;
begin
  {Retrieve Grid reference:}
  Grid:= Sender as TGrid;
  {Retrieve column and row indices:}
  ColIndex:= Column.Index;
  RowIndex:= Row;
  {Determine text to be drawn in cell:}
  GetGridCellText(ColIndex, RowIndex, CellStr);
  {Determine cell text position and bounds:}
  if CellStr<>'' then
    begin
      {Calculate size of cell string:}
      CellStringSize.cx:= Canvas.TextWidth(CellStr);
      CellStringSize.cy:= Canvas.TextHeight(CellStr);
      {Calculate posn of cell string:}
      if ColIndex=0 then
        begin
          {Align to centre}
          CellStrPosn.x:= (Bounds.Left + Bounds.Right - CellStringSize.cx) / 2;
        end
      else
        case (ColIndex-1) mod CFolderFieldCount of
          0:  CellStrPosn.x:= Bounds.Left + CCellMargin;    {Align to left}
          1..4: CellStrPosn.x:= (Bounds.Left +
                Bounds.Right - CellStringSize.cx) / 2 ;  {Align to centre}
          5:  CellStrPosn.x:= Bounds.Right - CCellMargin - CellStringSize.cx;
                           {Align to right}
        end;
      CellStrPosn.y:= (Bounds.Top + Bounds.Bottom - CellStringSize.cy) / 2;
      {Draw cell text:}
      {Calculate cell strings bounding rect:}
      CellStrRect.Left:= CellStrPosn.x;
      CellStrRect.Top:= CellStrPosn.y;
      CellStrRect.Right:= Bounds.Right - CCellMargin;
      CellStrRect.Bottom:= CellStrRect.Top +  CellStringSize.cy;
      Canvas.FillText(CellStrRect,  CellStr, True, 1.0, [], TTextAlign.Leading);
    end;
end;
```

On my first attempt, I hadn't explicitly set the `Grid1.DefaultDrawing` property, so it was True by default. However I assigned the event handler.

At some stage, I obtained some text being rendered in the grid cells, but it was very faint and in the wrong color. It looked as if the control had been painted with some semi-transparent background color after the text had been rendered, thereby changing the text color from the specified font color of black to pink.

This only happened if I removed the `OnGetCell` value event handler. When this handler was assigned to the grid, text was rendered automatically by the control, but not as I wanted it to appear, which was the reason why I want to override the automatic cell drawing with the custom `OnDrawColumnCell` event handler.

In my latest attempt, I set `Grid1.DefaultDrawing` set to False. I am finding that more or less the same code is producing no visible text whatsoever. However, when a cell is clicked, the correct text briefly appears in washed out colors, if an `OnGetValue` event handler has been assigned to the grid.

Can anyone suggest what might be preventing the text from being rendered by the `OnDrawColumnCell` event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the color of the text.

For example (just before `Canvas.FillText()`:

```
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
```

From the documentation for `Canvas.FillText()`:

> FillText is implemented by the TCanvas descendants to display a text string with the specified alignment, current font, and brush specified by the **Fill** and Font properties.